# Python | Preguntar por datos de una matriz

Tags: python

El usuario no debería por qué saber que, para **Python**, una matriz comienza por valor 0, tanto en sus filas como columnas de una **matriz**.
Entonces, ¿cómo puedo mejorar este código para que una persona pueda pedir el valor de la fila 1,  columna 1, **sin tener que poner 0 y 0**?

```
matriz = [[3.3, 6.1, 4.0], 
          [4.9, 5.7, 6.4]]

print(matriz)

fila = int(input("Fila: "))
columna = int(input("Columna: "))

if fila < len(matriz):
    if columna < len(matriz[fila]):
        print(matriz[fila][columna])
    else:
        print("Error en las columnas")
else:
    print("Error en las filas")
```

Comment: matriz[fila-1][columna-1]

Comment: como dijiste el usuario no tiene porque saber pero el desarrollador lo sabe, otra forma sería: fila = int(input("Fila: ")) -1
columna = int(input("Columna: "))-1